# How to insert dropdown list option into database

Tags: php, mysql

```
<tr>
    <td>Crew Name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="CrewName" id ="CrewName"required></td>     
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Crew Rank:</td>
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="CrewRank" id="CrewRank" required>
        <select>
            <?php
            $con = getDbConnect();
            if (!mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
                $queryStr = "SELECT rank "."FROM rankpage";
            }

            $result = mysqli_query($con, $queryStr);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<option>" . $row['rank'] . "</option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        </input>
    </td>       
</tr>
```

When I tried to use a dropdown list option for my input form, I could get the dropdown to show but the selected result doesn't go into the database. I'm not sure how to link my select option as an input type or the id to my selected result

Comment: You should give the `<select>` tag an id attribute, and each `<option>` tag should have a value attribute. Then you can take the *value* of the form element with the name you specify in the id of the `<select>` in your post request. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_form.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need link select option as input type. All you need is add name to the select element and add value for option element as:

```
<tr>
    <td>Crew Name:</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="CrewName" id ="CrewName" required />
    </td>     
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Crew Rank:</td>
    <td>
        <select name="CrewRank" id="CrewRank">
        <?php
             $con = getDbConnect();
             if (!mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
                 $queryStr = "SELECT rank " .
                             "FROM rankpage";

             }

             $result = mysqli_query($con, $queryStr);

             while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo "<option value=\"" . $row['rank'] . "\">" . $row['rank'] . "</option>";
             }
         ?>
         </select>
     </td>       
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the [value](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_value.asp) attribute of the option tag. You need to set the value to POST.

It should be something like:

```
echo "<option value=\"" . $row['rank'] . "\">" . $row['rank'] . "</option>";
```

And pass a `name` attribute (e.g `rank`) to `select` tag. You should get the value in `$_REQUEST['rank']`. You can you use `$_GET` or `$_POST`, depending on method passed in `<form>`

Comment: Can I have an example for passing a name attribute to select tag? I don't really get it

Comment: `<select name="rank">`